# Algorithm to pick a team of players that gives the closest ranking to a limit

Tags: c#, algorithm

Let's say that I have a database of 30 players. Database holds values for each of player's ranking in 3 elements (batting, bowling and fielding - ranks are 1-10 where 10 is the highest) and number of matches that a player played. To calculate team ranking I was thinking doing average of player's rank over 3 elements and adding it to team score.

---

There are 2 types of matches - friendly and league. 
Things to take into account when picking a team:

1. The team has to be balanced (e.g. fielding rank must not be >1 than batting and bowling).
2. All the players must have about the same number of games at the end of a season (with roughly 15 games in a season, games added to a player when user approves the team)

If user sets the match to be Friendly then the algorithm ignores players' ranking and picks least played players instead.

I need to make an algorithm that will give the best team for a match (10 players) with ranking as close to a limit(any number between 1 and 100) as possible (limit is set by a user).

**Here is what I looked at**

I looked at 0-1 *knapsack problem* but I don't know how to modify it so that the team is somewhat balanced. I also had a look at *linear programming* but I don't think I can use it here(Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Welcome to SO, this post looks like something more suitable for http://cs.stackexchange.com/ . Would you mind giving it a go there?

Comment: How is the number of games calculated/stored? How are they different between players?

Comment: The problem is underspecified as written. How is the rank of a team computed from the rank of its players? What's the limits for "not larger by huge amount"? What effect does "pick stronger team for league matches and weaker team for friendlies" have? What does "need to make an algorithm that will give the best team as possible" mean? Does it mean the strongest possible team for the next match, or the strongest possible set of teams over the whole season? If the latter, how do you compare different sets of teams? It seems like you don't yet have a programming problem.

Comment: @PaulHankin,  How is the rank of a team computed from the rank of its players? - I was thinking Calculating overall team rating by calculating the average over 3 elements and adding them up. What's the limits for "not larger by huge amount"? - not higher than 1. What effect does "pick stronger team for league matches and weaker team for friendlies" have? - I have a checkbox, if friendly match is ticked than the program ignores the ranking and picks lest played players. What does "need to make an algorithm that will give the best team as possible" mean? - just for the next match

Comment: @redshift0345 perhaps you could update the question with the details (for example, how you calculate team strength, and the specifics of "huge amount"), and exclude any irrelevant details (such condition 3)? I'm not sure this can be turned into a question that's suitable for stack-overflow, but those steps would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [constraint satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem).

You can solve problems like this on a case-by-case basis by using an algebraic modeling language like AMPL, or you can program a more flexible solution by using a [constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming) library.